# Mule 4 : What is the safest way to check and apply conditions based on data type of payload in Mule 4?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Scenario :
I have a payload as below :

```
{
    "message": "Hello world!"
}
```

Objective : Need to check the datatype of "message" field and apply a if else condition on it.

Some of the methods is tried is as Follows
Type 1 :

```
payload.message is String
```

Type 2:

```
typeOf(payload.message) ~= "String"
```

Type 3:

```
(typeOf(payload.message) as String) == "String"
```

Out of these which is the most reliable ways to check and apply the if else condition based on data type of a payload?

Note:
Type 2 coerces the left hand side value to match and check if its equal to right hand side so I am sure that is not a good idea. Any thoughts on 1 and 3 please?

Comment: As you said, type 2 is definitely not a way to go. I will prefer type 1. It does not require any String literal and it is cleaner. Both type 1 and type 3 are "reliable" as both of them will give you the correct result. But type 1 is way more readable and cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check the element type, use the first approach: `someElement is SomeType`. This expression returns a Boolean indicating whether the field is of the required type or not. Writing your if statement using this approach is cleaner than comparing the result of the typeOf function to a string (although both will work in the same way). Note that if the element is null, the expression will evaluate to false.

You could go with the second option too. When you use the typeOf function, it will return a string representing the element type. Note that if the field is null, typeOf will return "Null". You may use typeOf if you want to display the field type in the output. For example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
    {
        fieldName: key,
        fiedValue: value,
        fieldType: typeOf(value)
    }
)
```

using the input payload you provided, would result in:

```
[
    {
        "fieldName": "message",
        "fiedValue": "Hello world!",
        "fieldType": "String"
    }
]
```

One note about the '~=' operator: you usually use this operator when you want to compare to elements where you're not sure about their type. DataWeave will try to coerce them to a common type and do the actual comparison. The following example illustrates that:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    comparisonWithoutCoerce: (1 == "1"),
    comparisonWithCoerce: (1 ~= "1")
}
```

will return:

```
{
    "comparisonWithoutCoerce": false,
    "comparisonWithtCoerce": true
}
```

Lastly, the third approach could give a wrong answer: your are casting payload.message to string, and then check if the result is a string. This will give you a correct answer only if message is actually a string. To show you that the third approach won't work, check the following situation:

Input payload:

```
{
    "boolValue": true,
    "numValue": 12345,
    "strValue": "This is a test"
}
```

Using the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload pluck ((value, key, index) ->     {
        fieldName: key,
        fiedValue: value,
        fieldType: typeOf(value),
        fieldType2: typeOf(value as String)
    }
)
```

will result in:

```
[
  {
    "fieldName": "boolValue",
    "fiedValue": true,
    "fieldType": "Boolean",
    "fieldType2": "String"
  },
  {
    "fieldName": "numValue",
    "fiedValue": 12345,
    "fieldType": "Number",
    "fieldType2": "String"
  },
  {
    "fieldName": "strValue",
    "fiedValue": "This is a test",
    "fieldType": "String",
    "fieldType2": "String"
  }
]
```

Moreover, if some of the fields are arrays, the Dataweave Expression will fail as it cannot coerce arrays to strings.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, you can just use the `typeOf(value)` and use coerce (`ie: String, Array, Number, Boolean, Object, Null, DateTime, ...`)

See:

- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-typeof
- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types-coercion#type-coercion-table
- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-operators#equality-and-relational-operators

Example:

```
typeOf(payload.message) ~= "String"
```